# Выбор случайного элемента из массива с вероятностью

Tags: javascript

Можно выбрать случайное значение из массива с помощью кода:

```
config.targets[Math.floor(Math.random() * config.targets.length)]
```

А можно ли сделать так, чтобы в 75% случаев выбирались первые 10% содержимого массива?

Например, есть массив с числами от 1 до 100. Нужно, чтобы 75% рандома выпало на числа от 1 до 10.

Answer (score 4):

Если нужно обеспечить *минимум* 75% вероятности того, что случайно выбранные элементы окажутся в первой 1/10 части массива:

```
let max = config.targets.length; 
if (Math.random() < 0.75)                   // с вероятностью 75%... 
  max /= 10;                                // ...сокращаем диапазон до 10% от кол-ва элементов
let idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);  // это результат, "случайный" индекс элемента
```

*<sup>"Обеспечить" - это условно... На практике, в некотрых случаях может получиться немного меньше (величина отклонения зависит от кол-ва элементов, в первую очередь).</sup>*

```js
const config = { targets: new Array(100) }; 
let max = config.targets.length; 
for (let i = 0; i < max; i++)
  config.targets[i] = i + 1; 

const rndTarget = () => {
  let cMax = Math.random() >= 0.75 ? max : max * 0.1; 
  return config.targets[Math.floor(Math.random() * cMax)]; 
}; 
const testVol = 250;
for (var test = [], i = 0; i < testVol; i++) 
  test.push(rndTarget()); 
const tenPercentCount = test.reduce((r, v) => r += v <= 10, 0); 
console.log(`Из ${testVol} случайно выбранных элементов, ${(tenPercentCount / testVol * 100).toFixed(1)}% в первой 1/10 части массива.\nЧисла:\n${test.join(', ')}`);
```

Comment: Math.random же дает числа от 0 (включительно) до 1 (не включая)... это не значит, что 75% вероятность, это строго меньше 0.75, а не меньше или равно?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME это не очень то важно, т.к. рандом все равно не рандом =)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, верно, у меня 1% получается лишний. Спасибо

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, Math.random() никогда не возвращает .75, так что это неважно.

Answer (score 2):

Число запросов поделите пропорционально и в 75% случаев выборку меняйте на нужные 10% )

PS Ну вот так еще можно:

```
random = Math.round( Math.random() * 100);
if ( random >= 0 && random <= 75 ) Math.round( Math.random() * 10);
else if ( random > 75 && random <= 100 ) Math.round( Math.random() * 90 + 10);
```

Comment: round не в тему - он создаст погрешность на краях, да и обе границы становятся достижимыми. Надо через floor делать.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const f = (n, m, p) => () => Math.floor (Math.random () * (Math.random () < p ? m : n))

console.log (Array.from ({length: 100}, f (100, 10, 0.75)))
```