# Функция выбирающая случайное значение

Tags: javascript

Как написать функцию выбирающую случайное из, допустим пяти фиксированных значений в JS?
Допустим у нас есть массив:
const places = [palace, flat, house, bungalow, hotel]
и функция должна выбирать и возвращать какое то случайное значение из этого массива. Или не массив, как то ещё.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выбор случайного элемента из массива с вероятностью](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962349/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e)

Comment: Вариант без взвешенно-псевдослучайного значения есть в тексте вoпроса-дубликата.

Answer (score -2):

Ну как-то так =)

```js
let a = document.querySelector('.btn');

const places = ['palace', 'flat', 'house', 'bungalow', 'hotel'];

const random = places[Math.floor(Math.random() * places.length)];

a.addEventListener('click', e => {
if (e.target.className == 'btn') {
alert(random); 
window.location.reload(true);
}
})
```

```css
body{
user-select: none;      
}
       
.btn{
background: gold;
padding:10px;
font-size:20px;
text-align:center
}
```

```html
<div class ="btn">Жми (Случайное значение из массива)</div>
```